# I would like to find any other proxy addresses a user has that are not from this '*@mydomain.org' but are primary that start with 'SMTP:*'

Tags: windows, powershell

Using the below script:

```
Import-Csv "\\server\input.csv" | Foreach {Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($_.EID)'"  
-Properties EmployeeID, SamAccountName, Enabled, proxyAddresses } |  
Select-Object EmployeeID, SamAccountName, Enabled, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like '*@mycompany.org' ) -join ";"}}
```

I would also like to find any other proxy addresses a user has that are not from this '*@mydomain.org' but are primary that start with 'SMTP:*'

Example:

```
@{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like '*@mycompany.org' ) **AND ALSO LIKE THIS** -join ";"}}
```

Comment: As you can see I've deleted my answer(s) because I no longer want to spend time on this. My answer gave you solutions to your exact questions , but every time you seem to change the requirements and contradict what you are asking. Please take some time to formulate what you need EXACTLY, give REAL examples an desired output. Now, it's a constant battle...

Answer (score 0):

Getting a joined list of addresses that are not from a specific domain, but begin with "SMTP" indicating it's primary, then the calculated expression should look like the below.

```
@{
    Label = "ProxyAddresses"; 
    Expression = { 
        (
            $_.ProxyAddresses -notlike '*@mydomain.org' -and
            $_.ProxyAddresses -like 'SMTP*'
        ) -join ";"
    }
}
```

Filter out the domain you want to exlcude with the `-notlike` operator and only return primary addresses using `-like` to match from the beginning.